# How to get ip address?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I used the following code:

```
services:
  foo:
    class: Drupal\MYMODULE\Foo
    arguments: ['@request']
```

In MYMODULE/src/Foo.php

```
namespace Drupal\MYMODULE;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Foo {
  /**
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
   */
  protected $request;

  /**
   * Constructs a Foo object.
   *
   * @param Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   *   The request object.
   */
  public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function bar() {
    if ($ip == $this->request->getClientIp()) {
      drupal_set_message('ip', t('You may not ban your own IP address.'));
    }
  }

}
```

but this gives me error:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException'
>   with message 'The service "foo" has a dependency on a non-existent
>   service "request".

Comment: There is no service called `@request`, you need to use the service called `@request_stack`, and call `getCurrentRequest()` on the injected RequestStack object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code worked for me:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;
$ip_address = Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
```

Comment: **Note: The use of this wrapper in particular is especially discouraged.** https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x

Comment: Why do you need "use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;"? HttpFoundation is not referenced.

Answer (score 21):

According to [Get the user IP address](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/45/get-user-ip-address-remote-addr) and [Symfony HttpFoundation](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) you can get visitor IP by

first add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;` then

```
 \Drupal::request()->getClientIp()
```

Comment: With DI in the class, you would get the request from the RequestStack, which is available as a service.

Comment: It's better to use service injection instead of relying on the global `\Drupal` object.  See more details in my answer below.

Comment: *Note: The use of this wrapper in particular is especially discouraged* https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x

Answer (score 14):

The correct way to do this is via service injection.  This way your class is unit testable.

In your `mymodule.services.yml` file:

```
services:
  foo:
    class: Drupal\MYMODULE\Foo
    arguments: ['@request_stack']
```

In your class:

```
namespace Drupal\MYMODULE;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;    

class Foo {
  /**
   * The current request
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
   */
  protected $request;

  /**
   * Constructs a Foo object.
   *
   * @param Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $request_stack
   *   The request stack object.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack) {
    $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
  }

  public function bar() {
    $ip = $this->request->getClientIp();

    // Do something with $ip, just return it back as an example.
    return $ip;
  }

}
```

In your test file:

```
namespace Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Unit;

use Drupal\MYMODULE\Foo;
use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class FooTest extends UnitTestCase {

  public function testBar() {
    $request = $this->prophesize('\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request');
    $request->getClientIp()->willReturn('123.123.123.123');
    $request = $request->reveal();

    $request_stack = $this->prophesize('\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack');
    $request_stack->getCurrentRequest()->willReturn($request);
    $request_stack = $request_stack->reveal();

    $foo = new Foo($request_stack);

    $this->assertEquals($foo->bar(), '123.123.123.123');
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for completion, Does the above code create a drupal service, a reference to which can be obtained using `$ip_service = Drupal::service('foo');` and the IP address can be obtained by `$ip_service->bar()` ?

Answer (score 3):

What does the error you received tell you? It tells you that the service `request` does not exist. You can look/discover requests loaded by core reading the [core.services.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/8.2.x) file, and discover something similar, a service called `request_stack`.

The `request_stack` service provides [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!http-foundation!RequestStack.php/function/RequestStack%3A%3AgetCurrentRequest/8.2.x) with which you can get the current request. The static [\Drupal::request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x) is an example implementation of getting the current request.

```
  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
  }

  public function bar() {
    if ($ip == $this->request->getClientIp()) {
      drupal_set_message('ip', t('You may not ban your own IP address.'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Almost correct, but by assinging the request in the constructor, you're defeating the whole point of why request_stack exists :) The current request can change (sub requests and stuff like that). Always assing the request stack and get the request when you actually need it.

Comment: I have used exactly same code now and page gives "The drupal-8 page isn’t working

drupal-8 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"   without any error in log messages. Whenever i call this bar function inside any file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the ip in twig:

Suppose you want to get the ip in the page.html.twig file.

in your

**YOURTHEME.theme**

you can try

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['page']['ip'] = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();

}
```

in your template

**page.html.twig**

you can try:

```
{{ page.ip }}
```

Comment: This won’t work, as the code in preprocess functions is going to be cached until you flush the cache the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I make the following module for get ip address of visitors

create following route custom_location/custom_location.info.yml and following info

```
name: Custom Location
description: Custom Location.
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

custom_location/custom_location.links.menu.yml

```
location.admin:
  title: 'Location module settings'
  description: 'location'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route_name: location.content
  weight: 100
```

custom_location/custom_location.routing.yml

```
location.content:
  path: '/location'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_location\Controller\CustomLocation::content'
    _title: 'Ip Table'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

in the route custom_location/src/Controller/CustomLocation.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\custom_location\Controller\CustomLocation.
 */
namespace Drupal\custom_location\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class CustomLocation {
  public function content() {
    $ip_address = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
    $html = $ip_address;
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $html,
    );
  }
}
```

and visit in your path your location in /location and ready appear the ip

Comment: There are already answers showing how to get the IP from a controller, so this answer doesn't add anything to what the other answers already say. `\Drupal` should never be used in a controller class, though. It is also probable the output is going to be wrongly cached, without using cache tags or cache contexts.

Comment: oh yes you try the module, without \Drupal no working

Comment: See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/243888/199), which doesn't use `\Drupal` but correctly uses dependency injection.